# replacing the value in new data frame python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

As you seen on the image we have three columns so i need to write code that can create new columns called aa and replace when whever see A replace it with 1 or B replace it 2 ETC.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your data as text and not as an image. [mcve] [why not post images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9375102)

Comment: What is expected output if `B` is changed to `D` ?

Comment: let us  say we have only two coulmns first coulmn is Catecgories and have A, B , C ,and D A has value of 5 B has value of 9 etc  so what i want the code is to do is creating new column and whenever see the A he is gona replace it with 5 and whenever find b is gona replace it with  9 etc

Comment: Solution below not working?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df['aa'] = df['categories'].map(df.drop_duplicates('categories').set_index('categories')['WOF'])
```

Comment: Hi What i am trying to do is whenever have in coategies columns( A) have let us  say have  value 4 so on the new coulmns aa gona write 4 and let us say whenever (B) have value 8 in the WOF columns he is gona replace it with 8 on the new columns aa

Comment: @swe2010 - Not sure if understand, I try edit answer.